# monotouch uiwebview cannot find local html

Tags: uiwebview, xamarin.ios

I'm building an iPhone app on Monotouch. Part of my project use local website content. I copy all html, js, css and images used for the website in a folder and import this to my monotouch project. I have set build option for all of these files to Content.

I load the local web content like below:

> this.url = Path.Combine (NSBundle.MainBundle.BundlePath, "Content/index.html");
>   webView.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(new NSUrl(this.url, false)));

The problem is when I run the project, it cannot find my local website and the I got the message below when I try to debug:

> The requested URL was not found on this server.
>
> /Users/***********/Library/Application Support/iPhone
>   Simulator/4.3/Applications/092E0D85-92F4-4F4E-9CD2-3FBBCD797F76/Project.app/Content/index.html

The funny thing is when I copy the link to safari, the web is displayed without any problem

I have tried to clear and rebuild the project few times but nothing changes.

Can anyone help me with this?

I'm using OS X Moutain Lion 10.8.2, MonoDevelop 3.0.5, Monotouch 6.0.6, xcode 4.5.2

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you **really** using MonoTouch 3.0.2 ? that's a few years old and you're unlikely to find any people using this anymore. The current (stable) version is 6.0.6 and the last version compatible with Snow Leopard was 5.4 (using Xcode 4.2).

Comment: Sorry for typing mistake. I use MonoDevelop 3.0.5 and 5.x Monotouch. I am updating the whole system including OS X, xcode and Monotouch to the newest one. Hopefully it will solve the problem.

Comment: I have updated everything to the newest ones, but this still a problem. Could anyone have experience about this?

Comment: I *think* that when I've done this in the past, I just used urls that were relative to my project root.  So try just "Content/index.html"

Comment: Is the index.html in you project view actually in a folder named 'Content' (case sensitive). Is the filename 'index.html' all lowercase?

Answer (score 2):

It's strange, worked well for me.

Try this instead:

```
var fileName = "Content/index.html";
webView.LoadHtmlString (File.ReadAllText (fileName),
                        NSUrl.FromFilename (fileName));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use NSURLComponent as shown below. The parameters can be passed in the NSURLComponent Query property.

```
        string viewerPath = Path.Combine(NSBundle.MainBundle.BundlePath, string.Format("Content/pdfjs/web/{0}", _pdfViewerFileName));
        string queryString = string.Format("file={0}", _pdfFilePath);
        NSUrlComponents components = new NSUrlComponents(viewerPath);
        components.Query = queryString;
        Control.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(components.Url));
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help.

I've just realise that I have put parameters in the link, e.g: index.html?p1=v1&p2=v2, and it makes the link not work. If I remove those param, it's work without any problem.

Sorry for miss that information on my question.

Now, if I cannot do like normal website, how I can pass parameters to my local website?

Comment: if you need to add additional information to your question, please Edit it.  Adding comments as an answer is confusing.

Comment: That being said, when you pass parameters on the querystring typically there is something on the server (PHP, ASP.NET, Rails, etc) that interprets them and responds with HTML.  When you use local HTML pages in your app, they are just plain HTML, there is no server side processing taking place.

Comment: Using javascript, we still can parse the parameters for GET method. I have read somewhere said that using jQuery we can get params for POST as well but I've not tested it. The problem with MT is they consider the parameters as part of file name so they can't not find it. I have fixed my problem by removing the params from file name, then using MT execute javascript function to pass my parameters. Thanks for all your helps.

Comment: i have the same problem, any solution?

Comment: @jpintor I solved the problem by adding a forward slash after page name and it works very well, ex; index.html/?p1=v1&p2=v2

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to set Build Action for the htm to BundleResource - your code with this settings works for me !